# Why is my javascript email button not working? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email

I have a javascript image email button in the left column of my website.  It's a picture of an envelope, obviously meaning if you want to mail us, click here.  Here's the code:

```
<td>
<input type="image" src="http://www.ussvision.com/images/button-email.jpg" 
id="btnEmail" 
onclick="parent.location='mailto: @.com?subject=Check out USS Vision'" 
value="Email" alt="Email this page" />
</td>
```

But when I click this, nothing happens.  I don't want to use a 3rd party thing like addthis.  But I **WOULD** like it to be simple as possible on clients -- and if it doesn't have to open their default email, that'd be great, since in reduces stress on their RAM.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong, and why the e-mail button won't even open up the default e-mail client?  Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I tested this on a jsFiddle and worked just fine. Are you sure you have Javascript enabled? jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E63LK/

Comment: Thanks Hanlet, and screw the people who voted to have this question removed.  It was an honest question and a question that others might have issues with.  Hanlet, I am still not seeing the results in IE, FF, Chrome, or Safari ... it still just doesn't work.  And if you voted to negate this question, then you should be voted off of SE.  Thanks for looking into this Hanlet.  At least there are some commendable people here.

Comment: Wow, you too Mario ... okay, I'll clear the cache of all my browsers ... thanks Mario, and sorry for the troubles of going through this, but thanks for reading my issue.

Comment: Do you actually have an email client installed?

Comment: Hanlet, again, you are one of the good people who make this website work ... I've tried in separate browsers, but I'm sure now it's something to do with this PC, and not being near another PC, I can't test ... but thanks.  I'm still upset that good people like you and Mario are being laughed at by "experts" at SE.  I'll be sure to talk to someone about this.

Comment: Yes, Lee ... thanks, but I can take it from here ... right now, I'm kinda mad at the 4 people who negated this question .. but thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Your question has 0 upvotes, not -4. Also, why are you using JS for this? Can't you just create an anchor with image inside to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Jack, I was under the impression it was -4 ... but as far as creating an anchor, I don't know how to do this.  But thank you for pointing me in a separate direction, which is probably the right one ...

Comment: Have you tried onclick="window.location.href = 'mailto:a@b.c'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not answer your question, but I wouldn't use JavaScript for this.

```
<a title="Email this page" href="mailto:whoever@example.com?subject=Check%20out%20USS%20Vision">
  <img src="http://www.ussvision.com/images/button-email.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I was in a bad mood last night, but your answer works ... Thanks for taking the time to respond and thanks for sharing the knowledge ...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a button element instead of an input for that since that is semantically what it is (performs an action, not providing input or actually redirecting to a different URL). Also, try changing the call to window.location.href (as mentioned).

Button is a more general purpose element with a more lenient api.

Using an anchor-wrapped img element will work, but will make you more prone to being picked up by spam mail crawlers.